# How to change the font size in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, font-size

I have a `UIWebView` that `loadHTMLString` from an array.

I need this webView to change the font size dynamically

here is how i fill my WebView:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<p class=\"paragraph\"  style=\"float: right\"  >%@</p>",css,[[ contentArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"content"]]   baseURL:nil ];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put this code in your `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{

int fontSize = 20;
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize];
[webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
[jsString release];

}
```

Hope it helps ;)

**Update:**
For developers who enabled ARC, you should ignore adding:

```
[jsString release];
```

Comment: Thank you^99 times, thats worked for me

Comment: This is not working anymore for iOS 10.1.1, is there any alternative?